# javascript, jquery - сравнение двух нод

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть нода AAA в DOM. Я нахожу ее родителя и смотрю у него первого потомка A1, т.е. firstChild. Если этот первый потомок A1 является моим AAA - делаю какие-то действия. Вопрос: как мне сравнить две ноды меж собой на идентичность. Не идентичность контента нод, наличия классов и т.д. а просто два элемента DOM

Comment: `if (node1 == node2) { ... }`

Comment: да, спасибо! оказывается я просто неправильно сравнивал!

Comment: что подразумевать под идентичностью? просто если это одна и та же нода  - то работает предложенный метод, но если ноды разные  (размещены в разных местах), но имеют одни и те же атрибуты то решение будет другим.

Comment: Именно одна и та же, не точная копия. Вопрос решен, я неправильно сравнивал, поэтому получилась неувязка, заставившая меня писать сюда.

Answer (score 2):

Переменные, указывающие на узлы дерева DOM, - это ссылки. Поэтому определить ссылаются ли две переменные на один и тот же узел можно простой проверкой на равенство ссылок:

```
if (node1 == node2) { ... }
```